# how do I efficiently search before AND after an element for a key phrase

Tags: c++, search, vector, stl

I have a very large data set(ranging from 100,000 elements to 250,000 elements) that I am currently storing the data in a vector with the purpose of searching for a set of words. Given a phrase(e.g. "on, para") the function should find all words starting with the given phrase and push all matches on a queue.

To find the initial word I am using a binary search which seems to work great, but after the initial word is found I get stuck. How should I efficiently iterate before and after the element to find all similar words? The input is alphabetized so I know all other possible matches will occur before or after the element returned. I feel there must be a function in maybe `<algorithm>` that I could be taking advantage of. Here is a portion of the relevant code:

Binary search function:

```
int search(std::vector<std::string>& dict, std::string in)
{
    //for each element in the input vector
    //find all possible word matches and push onto the queue
    int first=0, last= dict.size() -1;
    while(first <= last)
    {
        int middle = (first+last)/2;
        std::string sub = (dict.at(middle)).substr(0,in.length());
        int comp = in.compare(sub);
        //if comp returns 0(found word matching case)
        if(comp == 0) {
            return middle;
        }
        //if not, take top half
        else if (comp > 0)
            first = middle + 1;
        //else go with the lower half
        else
            last = middle - 1;
    }
    //word not found... return failure
    return -1;
}
```

In `main()`

```
//for each element in our "find word" vector
for (int i = 0; i < input.size()-1; i++)
{
    // currently just finds initial word and displays
    int key = search(dictionary, input.at(i));
    std::cout << "search found " << dictionary.at(key) <<
                 "at key location " << key << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

std::lower_bound and iterating forward (you might use std::upper_bound, too):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    typedef std::vector<std::string> Dictionary;
    Dictionary dictionary = {
        "A", "AA", "B", "BB", "C", "CC"
    };
    std::string prefix("B");
    Dictionary::const_iterator pos = std::lower_bound(
        dictionary.begin(),
        dictionary.end(),
        prefix);
    for( ; pos != dictionary.end(); ++pos) {
        if(pos->compare(0, prefix.size(), prefix) == 0) {
            std::cout << "Match: " << *pos << std::endl;
        }
        else break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: would this be faster than a binary search then iterating? The goal of the program is the fastest performance possible

Answer (score 0):

You needed to build index not for each phrase, but for any sub-phrase. started from the word. For example, for dict-string "New York" you must keep index for two strings: "New York" and "York".
See my autocomplete demo, which illustrate this idea:

http://olegh.cc.st/autocomplete.html

As you see, this subsystem quick work with dictionaries, largest than your 250K elements.
Of course, I do not use there binary search, since it is slow. I use hashing instead.

Answer (score 0):

An ordered vector (list) is certainly one way to store data, but keeping the items organized has an efficiency cost.  And you did not mention whether your array was static or dynamic.  But there are other data structures which allow storing sorted data and have very good lookup times.

- Hash/Map - You could store your items as a hash/map and have very fast lookup, but finding the next and previous is problematic.
- Binary Tree/N-ary Tree/B-Tree - very good dynamic insert/delete performance, and also good lookup times, and the tree is ordered, so find next/previous is stable.
- Bloom filter - sometimes all you want to do is check whether an item is in your collection, and a bloom filter has very low false-positive, so it is a good choice.

Suppose you decompose your data into short subsequences (syllables), then you can have a tree of syllables, very fast lookup, and depending upon whether the tree is implemented as an ordered list or a hash/map, you may also be able to find next/previous.